# Spring message-driven-channel-adapter: handling connection refused error

Tags: spring-integration, mqtt

I want to configure my message-driven-channel-adapter in such a way that I can grab the 'connection refused' error in case when: 
    1) the message broker is down or 2) A wrong broker URL is specified

I tried doing this with the code below but it did not work:

```
<int:channel id="invalidChannel" />

<int-mqtt:message-driven-channel-adapter 
     id="myAdapter" 
     client-id="${inbound.client.id}"
     url="${host.url}"
     topics="${inbound.topic}"
     channel="incomingChannel"
     error-channel="errorChannel"
     client-factory="clientFactory" />

<int:exception-type-router input-channel="errorChannel">
        <int:mapping exception-type="java.net.ConnectException" channel="invalidChannel" />
    </int:exception-type-router>


<int:service-activator id="ErrorActivator" 
            input-channel="invalidChannel" 
            ref="errorListener" 
            method="processError" />


<bean id="errorListener" class="com.ErrorListener"  />
```

The processError() method is defined as below:

```
public void processError(Message<MessageHandlingException> message)
    {
        System.out.println("an error / exception occured");
    }
```

I am trying to grab the exception which is logged as below in case of connection exception:

```
Unable to connect to server (32103) - java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:590)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.TCPNetworkModule.start(TCPNetworkModule.java:70)
        ... 2 more
```

Can someone please help ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

`Connection refused` error isn't a part of Messaging flow, so it isn't handled by the `errorChannel`. M-m-m... Just because it is caused before any `Message` appears.

**UPDATE**

Starting with Spring Integration `4.2.2` the `MqttConnectionFailedEvent` is available for these cases.

See more information in the Reference Manual: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mqtt.html

Comment: No-op. There is on such a hook in the `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`. You can overcome it, though, using `client.connect(connectionOptions)` manually in some other component via the same `MqttPahoClientFactory`.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. The approach you suggested will work when the broker is unavailable while starting the application. However, if the broker goes down while the application is running, then this will require handling in some other way

Comment: There's not currently any notification. You would have to run a connection checker in a loop. I have opened a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3878) to have the framework emit an `ApplicationEvent` when connecting fails.

Comment: Thanks, @GaryRussell! That is what I dreamed off this night :-)

Comment: Another work around would be a custom log appender to detect this log entry `logger.error("Error connecting or subscribing to " + Arrays.asList(this.getTopic()), e);`.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer. Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066471/spring-mqtt-catch-connectexception