# spring mqtt: catch ConnectException

Tags: java, spring, exception, spring-integration, mqtt

I have a question about spring.

I make a connection with MQTT broker using Spring-Paho `MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`. Here is a java config part:

```
@Bean
@Description("mqtt inbound adapter: receives mqtt messages")
public MessageProducer mqttInboundAdapter() {
    log.info("creating mqtt inbound adapter");
    MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
            new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(
                    env.getProperty("mqtt.hostname")+":" +env.getProperty("mqtt.port"), 
                    "myClient",
                    "#");
    adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
    adapter.setConverter(new DefaultPahoMessageConverter());
    adapter.setQos(1);
    adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
    adapter.setErrorChannel(mqttErrorChannel());
    return adapter;
}
```

When the broker is off and the connection is not establiched the `ConnectException` is thrown. It is great, but I want not only to see the trace of it in the log, but also receive a warning email.

I hoped that it could be realized with the help of `mqttErrorChannel`, but `ConnectException` [is not the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33534977/spring-message-driven-channel-adapter-handling-connection-refused-error) of usage of error channels. Is there any way to catch the ConnectException to another channel or in another way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Spring Integration `4.2.2` the `MqttConnectionFailedEvent` is emitted, when we lost connection or can't connect on subscribe.

You can catch that `ApplicationEvent` for example with the `ApplicationEventListeningMessageProducer` and send it to the appropriate channel.

See more information in the Reference Manual: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/mqtt.html